# SQL Compare Two Tables and Update one of them

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have two Tables, A, B. A has two columns A1 and A2. B has two columns B1 and B2. In my case Some of the value in A2 and B2 are same, for such cases I want to update A1 = B1. So A1 should take the value from B1 when A2 = B2.
I have written the following query but it makes all the values NULL in table A. Can anyone help me fix this?

```
Update A
SET A.A1 = (Select B1 from B Where A.A2 = B.B2)
```

Comment: Your inner `SELECT` will return update `A.A1` to `NULL` if there is no matching row.

Comment: There are matching rows. Many values in A2 are equal to B2

Comment: Yes, but those that do not have a match will be set to `NULL`. Use a `JOIN` as Tim's answer.

Answer (score 9):

You could use an `INNER JOIN` to identify which records should be updated:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.A1 = B.B1
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
    ON A.A2 = B.B2
```

The nice thing about this approach logically is that the only records which will get updated are the ones which survive the `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: It worked Tim. Thank you very much. I am new to SQL. Your help is appreciated. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I like the inner join approach from Tim Biegeleisen. However, I would also use this to test by issuing a SELECT first.

```
select
  a.ai
, b.bi
, a.a2
, b.b2
 from a inner join b
 on a.a2 = b.b2
```

Examine to be sure the the values you are updating (col1) with new values (col2) are correct for the 3rd and 4th columns.